# Detect incoming outgoing or ringing calls while the app is closed or open

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-workmanager

As we all know Broadcast receiver is not working anymore, kindly suggest me a better way to get this done.

Comment: Broadcast receivers do work.  Instead of posting a general statement maybe try posting actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Reccelly, I had used firebase to listen to event call incomming. Android system don't kill firebase service when it run in background. Now, I  only know this way.

Comment: what if don't want to use firebase services? is it possible with workmanager or background services?

Comment: I think WakefulBroadcastReceiver will works for you.

Comment: wakefulbroadcastreceiver is deprecated